# Using Xamarin Studio, how can I set a constraint value to 0?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, constraints, xamarin-studio

Using the XCode interface builder this works fine, you can set constraint values to 0 as you would any value.

However, which the iOS designer in Xamarin, if you enter 0 as a value it doesn't accept the change and just sets back to its original value. This just seems like a bug to me?

Has anyone experienced this?

I am using the latest stable release at the current time (v6.1 - Build 5441)

Comment: This does not answer your question but did you know you could open xcode by right clicking on your storybord or .xib file and select open with xcode?

Comment: Yeah I do use that occasionally and this is actually the only way to achieve this, but it's just a pain to keep swapping IDEs just because Xamarin Studio can't set the value to 0. It's also more of a pain at the moment because this latest version is incompatible with the new .storyboard format that was shipped with Xcode 8 recently